# How to programmatically write content into json file

Tags: java, json, liferay, portlet, filewriter

How to programmatically write `json` data into `json` file, located in Documents and Media of Liferay?

I have a portlet, in which I am receiving `json data`. I want to write the received `json` data into a `json` file located in Documents and media of Liferay portal.

I am able to write data into physical file path inside a portlet. But not able to find the physical file path of folder in Documents and media. I know it is in `data/document_library`. But not able to find the folder `id`.
Also file is encrypted with version number.

So I think it won't be of any use even if I get the `folder id` properly.

Can you guys suggest any feasible solutions on the same. I am new to Liferay.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the physical path of the file is plain wrong. Instead, use Liferay's API to store files in the Document Library. Watch out for API interfaces starting with `DL`, e.g. `DLFileEntryService`. There are plenty of examples for interacting with that API.

Storing files in `data/document_library` is one option (the default configuration) but the data can be anywhere else on disk, in a database or in other system. Plus, the metadata is always in the database. And it only gets there when you use the proper APIs.